# Can I pass parameters to preExecute() method in async task?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-view

Id like to manipulate a specific view in an async task before the backround task executes but not sure how I can pass the required parameters to the method. I Just get a null pointer when I do something like this

```
class CalcFib extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Long> {

    private View v;
    private int index;

    public CalcFib(int i){
        this.index = i;

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //do something with this.index
    }

    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(Integer... params) {

        long t = 1234;
        return t;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {

    }
}
```

Comment: NOTE: OP updated the code in their own question to reflect the accepted answer so the code above is correct and working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add a constructor to `CalcFib` and pass the required values to an instance through the constructor.

Comment: This is bang on. And just for the record, OP updated the code in their own question to reflect this. So if you're thinking that the code in the original question should work, it's because it does.